# iOS - UIImagePickerController crashes on device

Tags: ios, crash, uiimagepickercontroller

This code runs fine in the simulator, but crashes every time on the device (iPhone 3GS), right when I take the picture. Is there something wrong with this code? When I Profile with Allocations, active memory is only 3-4 MB when it crashes, so it doesn't seem that the app is running out of memory. I'm using ARC.

```
-(IBAction)chooseImageNew:(UIButton*)sender
{
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{

    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;

    imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
}
else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"No Camera Available." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

}

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
UIImage *img = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];
self.userPicture.image = img;
[self.images replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:img];

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: annnnnd, is there a crash log generated when it crashes on the device?

Comment: Under Device Logs, there's this:  My App Name <65a5da31738337b18bc1a9e2dcaaaaaa>   23371 (jettisoned) (active)

Comment: Run the app from Xcode and post whatever appears in the console and the stack trace.

Answer (score 5):

Does this `self.userPicture.image = img;`
 assign the image to an UIImageView?

Before you do that you have to resize it, the ImagePickerController callback gives you an image in JPEG representation, but as soon as you display that image in an UIImageView the data gets decoded to raw format. The 3GS takes pictures with 2048x1536 resolution, which translates into something like 12 MB data, which might already be too much for the 3GS.

There are some categories for resizing available, like this excellent one:
http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

If you use this just call this before assigning to the imageView:

`UIImage* pickedImage = [sourceImage resizedImageWithContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit bounds:CGSizeMake(960, 960) interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];`

Comment: this was a great suggestion. I implemented it, and it doesn't crash. However, I still get "Received memory warning." and the image does not display in the UIImageView (self.userPicture). How are we supposed to use the UIImagePickerController if it uses so much memory?

Comment: The reason it's not getting displayed is because the memory warning is causing the entire view to get reloaded. Apparently this is a quite common issue, but even though I can find many threads about this, there aren't any good answers. What is the recommended way to deal with the camera using so much memory?

Answer (score 2):

Your reference to the picker is released when your method returns. Make this an ivar:

> UIImagePickerController *imagePicker

EDIT: also, don't release (ARC: nil out) this ivar until AFTER the last delegate message: that is, dispatch a block to the main thread so its done one run loop spin afterwards! [Ask me how I know this :-) ]